# Python subprocess "object has no attribute 'fileno'" error

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

This code generates "AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'fileno'" when run with Python 2.5.1

Code:

```
def get_blame(filename): 
    proc = []
    proc.append(Popen(['svn', 'blame', shellquote(filename)], stdout=PIPE))
    proc.append(Popen(['tr', '-s', r"'\040'"], stdin=proc[-1]), stdout=PIPE)
    proc.append(Popen(['tr', r"'\040'", r"';'"], stdin=proc[-1]), stdout=PIPE)
    proc.append(Popen(['cut', r"-d", r"\;", '-f', '3'], stdin=proc[-1]), stdout=PIPE)
    return proc[-1].stdout.read()
```

Stack:

```
function walk_folder in blame.py at line 55
print_file(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), path)

function print_file in blame.py at line 34
users = get_blame(filename)

function get_blame in blame.py at line 20
proc.append(Popen(['tr', '-s', r"'\040'"], stdin=proc[-1]), stdout=PIPE)

function __init__ in subprocess.py at line 533
(p2cread, p2cwrite,

function _get_handles in subprocess.py at line 830
p2cread = stdin.fileno()
```

This code should be working the python docs describe [this usage](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements).

Comment: Closing this as "too localized" is ridiculous as *I* found it useful, years later. This is the nature of programming problems - they are always niche problems applicable to a narrow userbase. But they ARE useful... SO makes me sad these days, which is why I don't use it often any more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three things

First, your ()'s are wrong.

Second, the result of `subprocess.Popen()` is a process object, not a file.

```
proc = []
proc.append(Popen(['svn', 'blame', shellquote(filename)], stdout=PIPE))
proc.append(Popen(['tr', '-s', r"'\040'"], stdin=proc[-1]), stdout=PIPE)
```

The value of `proc[-1]` isn't the file, it's the process that contains the file.

```
proc.append(Popen(['tr', '-s', r"'\040'"], stdin=proc[-1].stdout, stdout=PIPE))
```

Third, don't do all that `tr` and `cut` junk in the shell, few things could be slower.  Write the `tr` and `cut` processing in Python -- it's faster and simpler.

Comment: Was the 'Tree' for humour - or did you mean "Three"?

Comment: The script will only be used on linux. It's more of a one off tool than anything else. Using shell tools was easier than trying to figure out the python equivalent. Just dropping in a working shell command is easier than debugging regex.

Comment: There's no complex regex required to parse the svn blame output.  Using shell scripts is -- in the long run -- MORE complex because the shell language is such a collection of random features.  Python is -- in the long run -- simpler.

Comment: In the long run of course. I was converting a bash script that didn't work very well into python.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few weird things in the script,

- Why are you storing each process in a list? Wouldn't it be much more readable to simply use variables? Removing all the `.append()s` reveals an syntax error, several times you have passed stdout=PIPE to the `append` arguments, instead of Popen:

  ```
  proc.append(Popen(...), stdout=PIPE)
  ```

  So a straight-rewrite (still with errors I'll mention in a second) would become..

  ```
  def get_blame(filename): 
      blame = Popen(['svn', 'blame', shellquote(filename)], stdout=PIPE)
      tr1 = Popen(['tr', '-s', r"'\040'"], stdin=blame, stdout=PIPE)
      tr2 = Popen(['tr', r"'\040'", r"';'"], stdin=tr1), stdout=PIPE)
      cut = Popen(['cut', r"-d", r"\;", '-f', '3'], stdin=tr2, stdout=PIPE)
      return cut.stdout.read()
  ```
- On each subsequent command, you have passed the Popen object, *not* that processes `stdout`. From the ["Replacing shell pipeline"](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) section of the subprocess docs, you do..

  ```
  p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
  p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
  ```

  ..whereas you were doing the equivalent of `stdin=p1`.

  The `tr1 =` (in the above rewritten code) line would become..

  ```
  tr1 = Popen(['tr', '-s', r"'\040'"], stdin=blame.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
  ```
- You do not need to escape commands/arguments with subprocess, as subprocess does not run the command in any shell (unless you specify `shell=True`). See the [Security](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#security)section of the subprocess docs.

  Instead of..

  ```
  proc.append(Popen(['svn', 'blame', shellquote(filename)], stdout=PIPE))
  ```

  ..you can safely do..

  ```
  Popen(['svn', 'blame', filename], stdout=PIPE)
  ```
- As S.Lott suggested, don't use subprocess to do text-manipulations easier done in Python (the tr/cut commands). For one, tr/cut etc aren't hugely portable (different versions have different arguments), also they are quite hard to read (I've no idea what the tr's and cut are doing)

  If I were to rewrite the command, I would probably do something like..

  ```
  def get_blame(filename): 
      blame = Popen(['svn', 'blame', filename], stdout=PIPE)
      output = blame.communicate()[0] # preferred to blame.stdout.read()
      # process commands output:
      ret = []
      for line in output.split("\n"):
          split_line = line.strip().split(" ")
          if len(split_line) > 2:
              rev = split_line[0]
              author = split_line[1]
              line = " ".join(split_line[2:])

              ret.append({'rev':rev, 'author':author, 'line':line})

      return ret
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You want the stdout of the process, so replace your `stdin=proc[-1]` with `stdin=proc[-1].stdout`

Also, you need to move your paren, it should come after the `stdout` argument.

```
 proc.append(Popen(['tr', '-s', r"'\040'"], stdin=proc[-1]), stdout=PIPE)
```

should be:

```
 proc.append(Popen(['tr', '-s', r"'\040'"], stdin=proc[-1].stdout, stdout=PIPE))
```

Fix your other `append` calls in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

looks like syntax error. except first append the rest are erroneous (review brackets).

Comment: it's not what? every single answer included the fact that you have a problem with your brackets! it is a syntax issue, on top of piping of course.

Comment: It's a syntax issue but not a syntax error oddly enough. The code is directly pasted from the script I had. The error was the error that was generated. A syntax error would have killed the script in the middle of the function definition. The function actually gets called. I think it's because list.append() accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: no it doesn't. append is never called, because error occurs at the initialisation of Popen, which is fairly obvious from your error stack. so yes it is a syntax error on your part. no SyntaxError raised, but a syntax issue nevertheless.

Comment: So it is... interesting. I've been doing way too much compiled stuff lately. I'm forgetting how dynamic python is.

Answer (score -2):

Like S.Lott said, processing the text in Python is better.

But if you want to use the cmdline utilities, you can keep it readable by using `shell=True`:

```
cmdline = r"svn blame %s | tr -s '\040' | tr '\040' ';' | cut -d \; -f 3" % shellquote(filename)
return Popen(cmdline, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: There's a huge security risk in using shell=True, as well as a real possibility that the process could hang between piping data from one command to the next without providing any real error handling.

Comment: @SummerEla fair enough, although it's a tradeoff - people do it in shell scripts all the time and accept it there. It's possible to make the same tradeoff when scripting in Python as well. Readability and simplicity have their value too